# Averaging vectors with the same norm results in a vector with norm $\leq$ original norm

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, normed-spaces

Suppose that we have a list of vectors, where each vector's norm is 3.

Then, if we average these vectors (per element), the final vector's norm will be $\leq$ 3 .

This is only empirically speaking. I also noticed that more vectors i average whose norm is 3 for example, the closer I get to 3 as an upper bound. Is there some sort of proof for this or was this random?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the triangle identity and absolute homogeneity (which are included in the definition of a norm), if $\forall k\in\{ 0,\dots,n\}, \mathcal{N}(u_k)=v$:
$$
\mathcal{N}(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^nu_k)\leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^n\mathcal{N}(u_k)
= v$$

As to the 'getting closer' part, this is not true in general: take the norm $||v||_1 = \sum_{i=0}^1 |v_i|$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $v_1 = (1,0)^T, v_2=-v_1$.

Comment: Could you please explain this part:  $\mathcal{N}(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^nu_k)\leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^n\mathcal{N}(u_k)$ ? When I average random vectors and then taking the 2nd norm, for example, the result is just random.

Comment: What do you not understand? Sure the norm of the average might be somewhat random based on the vectors you choose, but it will always be less than or equal to the norm of the vectors.

Comment: Yeah, it's alright. I just realised that in your notation the $u_k$'s are normed to $v$ already.